# Using KDD cup 99 dataset and machine learning with R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to use the KDD cup 99 dataset with R but unfortunately, I get very bad results. Basically, the predictor is guessing (~50% error on the cross-validation set). There is probably a bug in my code but I can't find where.

The KDD cup 99 dataset is composed of around 4 millions examples which are separated in 4 different classes of attacks + the class "normal". First, I split the dataset into 5 files (one for each class + one for the class "normal") and I convert the non-numerical data into numerical ones. For the moment, I am working on the class "Remote to Local" (r2l). I select some features according to the results of a paper on the topic. Afterwards, I sample a number of "normal" instances equal to the number of r2l instances to avoid the problem of skewed class. I also replace all the labels for the different types of r2l attacks by the label "attack" so I can train a two-classes classifier. Then I join the sample to the r2l instances in one new dataset. Finally, I apply a 10-fold cross-validation to assess my model which is built using SVM and I get the worst results in the history of machine learning... :(

Here is my code:

```
r2l <- read.table("kddcup_r2l.data",sep=",",header=T)
#u2r <- read.table("kddcup_u2r.data",sep=",",header=T)
#probe_original <- read.table("kddcup_probe.data",sep=",",header=T)
#dos <- read.table("kddcup_dos.data",sep=",",header=T)
normal <- read.table("kddcup_normal.data",sep=",",header=T)

#probe <- probe_original[sample(1:dim(probe_original)[1],10000),]

#   Features selected by the three algorithms svm, lgp and mars
#   for the different classes of attack
########################################################################

features.r2l.svm <- c("srv_count","service","duration","count","dst_host_count")
features.r2l.lgp <- c("is_guest_login","num_access_files","dst_bytes","num_failed_logins","logged_in")
features.r2l.mars <- c("srv_count","service","dst_host_srv_count","count","logged_in")
features.r2l.combined <- unique(c(features.r2l.svm,features.r2l.lgp,features.r2l.mars))



#       Sample the training set containing the normal labels
#       for each class of attack in order to have the same number 
#       of training data belonging to the "normal" class and the 
#       "attack" class
#######################################################################

normal_sample.r2l <- normal[sample(1:dim(normal)[1],dim(r2l)[1]),]


# This part was useful before the separation normal/attack because 
# attack was composed of different types for each class
######################################################################

normal.r2l.Y <- matrix(normal_sample.r2l[,c("label")]) 


#######################################################################
#       Class of attack Remote to Local (r2l)
#######################################################################

#   Select the features according to the algorithms(svm,lgp and mars)
#   for this particular type of attack. Combined contains the 
#   combination of the features selected by the 3 algorithms  
#######################################################################
#features.r2l.svm <- c(features.r2l.svm,"label")
r2l_svm <- r2l[,features.r2l.svm]
r2l_lgp <- r2l[,features.r2l.lgp]
r2l_mars <- r2l[,features.r2l.mars]
r2l_combined <- r2l[,features.r2l.combined]
r2l_ALL <- r2l[,colnames(r2l) != "label"]

r2l.Y <- matrix(r2l[,c("label")])
r2l.Y[,1] = "attack"



#   Merge the "normal" instances and the "r2l" instances and shuffle the result
############################################################################### 

r2l_svm.tr <- rbind(normal_sample.r2l[,features.r2l.svm],r2l_svm)
r2l_svm.tr <- r2l_svm.tr[sample(1:nrow(r2l_svm.tr),replace=F),]
r2l_lgp.tr <- rbind(normal_sample.r2l[,features.r2l.lgp],r2l_lgp)
r2l_lgp.tr <- r2l_lgp.tr[sample(1:nrow(r2l_lgp.tr),replace=F),]
r2l_mars.tr <- rbind(normal_sample.r2l[,features.r2l.mars],r2l_mars)
r2l_mars.tr <- r2l_mars.tr[sample(1:nrow(r2l_mars.tr),replace=F),]
r2l_ALL.tr <- rbind(normal_sample.r2l[,colnames(normal_sample.r2l) != "label"],r2l_ALL)
r2l_ALL.tr <- r2l_ALL.tr[sample(1:nrow(r2l_ALL.tr),replace=F),]

r2l.Y.tr <- rbind(normal.r2l.Y,r2l.Y)
r2l.Y.tr <- matrix(r2l.Y.tr[sample(1:nrow(r2l.Y.tr),replace=F),])

#######################################################################
#
#       10-fold CROSS-VALIDATION to assess the models accuracy
#
####################################################################### 

# CV for Remote to Local
########################    
cv(r2l_svm.tr, r2l_lgp.tr, r2l_mars.tr, r2l_ALL.tr, r2l.Y.tr)
```

And the cross-validation function:

```
cv <- function(svm.tr, lgp.tr, mars.tr, ALL.tr, Y.tr){  

Jcv.svm_mean <- NULL

#Compute the size of the cross validation
# =======================================
index=sample(1:dim(svm.tr)[1])
size.CV<-floor(dim(svm.tr)[1]/10)

Jcv.svm <- NULL

#Start 10-fold Cross validation
# =============================
for (i in 1:10) {
    #   if m is the size of the training set 
    #   (nr of rows in svm.tr for example)
    #   take n observations for test and (m-n) for training
    #   with n << m (here n = m/10)
    # ===================================================
    i.ts<-(((i-1)*size.CV+1):(i*size.CV))   
    i.tr<-setdiff(index,i.ts)

    Y.tr.tr <- as.factor(Y.tr[i.tr])    
    Y.tr.ts <- as.factor(matrix(Y.tr[i.ts],ncol=1))

    svm.tr.tr <- svm.tr[i.tr,]
    svm.tr.ts <- svm.tr[i.ts,]  


    # Get the model for the algorithms 
    # ==============================================


    model.svm <- svm(Y.tr.tr~.,svm.tr.tr,type="C-classification")

    # Compute the prediction 
    # ==============================================
    Y.hat.ts.svm <- predict(model.svm,svm.tr.ts)

    # Compute the error 
    # ==============================================

    h.svm <- NULL

    h.svm <- matrix(Y.hat.ts.svm,ncol=1)

    Jcv.svm <- c(Jcv.svm ,sum(!(h.svm == Y.tr.ts))/size.CV)
    print(table(h.svm,Y.tr.ts)) 

}

Jcv.svm_mean <- c(Jcv.svm_mean, mean(Jcv.svm))

d <- 10
print(paste("Jcv.svm_mean: ", round(Jcv.svm_mean,digits=d) ))   
}
```

I obtain very strange results. It seems that the algorithm doesn't really see any difference between the instances. It looks like a guess more than a prediction. I also tried with the class of attack "Probe" but obtain the same results. The paper that I mentioned earlier had a 30% accuracy on the class r2l and 60-98% (depending on the polynomial degree) on probe.

Here is the prediction for one of the 10 fold of the cross-validation:

h.svm(attack) & Y.tr.ts(attack) --> 42 instances

h.svm(attack) & Y.tr.ts(normal.) --> 44 instances

h.svm(normal.) & Y.tr.ts(attack) --> 71 instances

h.svm(normal.) & Y.tr.ts(normal.) --> 68 instances

I would be really grateful if somebody could tell me what is wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Apparently, noone seem to answer... Is it because my question is not well formed? or is it because noone sees what is wrong?

Comment: This belongs on [DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) but is too old to migrate now. Recommend you reask there.

Answer (score 3):

couldn't be sure if this is your problem, but there are known problems with that data set.
http://www.bruggerink.com/~zow/GradSchool/KDDCup99Harmful.html
sorry I couldn't help with code, I don't know R :/